# Can Mediator.Net support multi event handlers as well as inheritance?

Tags: mediator

can mediator.net support multi event handlers? i want to have multiple handlers listen to the same event and do different thing.

```
public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
{
    public Guid Id { get; }

    public SimpleCommand(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mediator.Net, you can have as many event handlers as you want as long as the message implement the IEvent interface, but only 1 command handler. From your code example, as SimpleCommand is a ICommand which mean that you can only have one handler for it.

In terms of inheritance, ICommand handler need to be the exact type which mean no inheritance is supported. For IEvent, as long as the Handler is assignable from the message type then it should get called, so inheritace is in.